# Codeigniter Post keeps adding up

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could not think of a a better title for this question. Anyways here is the problem.

I have a simple contact form. If the user goes to that page and enters wrong info (no email or message) then everything seems to work. I get the validation errors. But if they put the wrong information in say 6 times in a row, then click the browsers "back" button. They do not go to the previous page. They have to click 6 or 7 times to return to previous page. Am I doing something wrong?

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $data['title'] = "Contact Us";
        $data['main'] = 'contact';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->vars($data);
            $this->load->view('template');
        }
        else
        {
             $contactdata['username'] = $this->input->post('email');
             $contactdata['title'] = "Contact Success";
             $contactdata['main'] = 'contactsuccess';
             $this->load->vars($contactdata);
             $this->load->view('template');
        }
}
```

Comment: Its not because of code I think its because user have submit the form many time and each time browser saved it in history. That's why they have to clicks the back button many times :D

Comment: Saleem any way to overcome this issue then?

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea. Try posting with javascript tag May be someone out there will help you

Comment: It is OK. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

you can check the request if it is come from a post request

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $data['title'] = "Contact Us";
        $data['main'] = 'contact';

        if($this->input->post()){

               $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','required');

              if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
              {
                  $this->load->vars($data);

              }
              else
              {
                 $contactdata['username'] = $this->input->post('email');
                 $contactdata['title'] = "Contact Success";
                 $contactdata['main'] = 'contactsuccess';
                 $this->load->vars($contactdata);
             }
        }
        else{
                 $this->load->vars($data);
        }

        $this->load->view('template');

  }
```